# Colours in Google Stacked Chart

Tags: r, googlevis

I am trying to change the colours in a goolge stacked chart. I can not seem to replicate the suggestion given for color argument in the help file of 'gvisSteppedAreaChart'

```
df=data.frame(year=1:3, val1=c(1,3,4), val2=c(23,12,32))

SteppedArea1 <- gvisSteppedAreaChart(df, xvar="country", yvar=c("val1", "val2"),
                                     options=list(isStacked=TRUE))
plot(SteppedArea1)

SteppedArea1 <- gvisSteppedAreaChart(df, xvar="country", yvar=c("val1", "val2"),
                                     options=list(isStacked=TRUE),
                                     colors="{color:[red','#004411']}")
plot(SteppedArea2)
```

I think there is a typo in the help file, or perhaps I am not specifying a HTML color string correctly (my HTML is very hazy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the example in the docs for that function were missing a single quote. And your colors arg needs to be inside the `options` list. Note that the example is showing that you can use color names (e.g., red), and hex codes (e.g., #004411). This works for me:

```
library(googleVis)
df=data.frame(country=c("US", "GB", "BR"), val1=c(1,3,4), val2=c(23,12,32))
SteppedArea2 <- gvisSteppedAreaChart(df, xvar="country", yvar=c("val1", "val2"),
                                 options=list(isStacked=TRUE, colors="['red','#004411']"))
plot(SteppedArea2)
```